# Access Angular model instance from external JS?

Tags: angularjs

My 'ProjectsCtrl' contains this function for adding a new project to a parent resource:

```
$scope.addProject = function(client){
    $scope.client = client;
    $scope.newProject.client_id = client.id;
    project = Project.save($scope.newProject);
    $scope.newProject = {};
}
```

The 'client' argument is taken from the view wherein I have an `ng-submit="addProject(client)"` within an `ng-repeat="client in clients"` block.

In another .js file I am trying to get reference to that client instance in order to update the view after pushing some data using server side events. Here is that code:

```
var pSource = new EventSource('/administration/projects/events');
pSource.addEventListener('projects.create', function(e){
    var project = $.parseJSON(e.data);
    var projectCtrl = angular.element($(".project-list")).scope();

    projectCtrl.$apply(function(){
        projectCtrl.client.projects.push(project);
    });
});
```

The problem is that the project is always appended onto the first client instance, and not the one being passed to the `addProject()` function.

If I do `client.projects.push(project);` within the controller, then it works correctly.  How can I get a reference to that client instance from outside of the controller?

Comment: whenever need to tie data between different parts of app....use a service to store the data, inject service whereever need access. Alternatively can broadcast an event that contains the data

Comment: @charlietfl doesn't this leave me with the same issue of needing to access a model instance from outside of Angular? Or maybe I am misunderstanding you.  This is my first foray into Angular.

Comment: Could store all the data in a global array, pass that global array to angular . Would be more ideal to use what's in other file as angular service

Comment: @charlietfl I want to avoid updating the entire dataset and only update the small area of the view where the new data is being inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up passing the $index of the parent resource as a model attribute on the child object and using that to push to the correct position.

e.g.

```
var clientCtrl = angular.element($(".client-list")).scope();
var project = $.parseJSON(e.data);
var projectCtrl = angular.element($(".project-list")).scope();

projectCtrl.$apply(function(){
    clientCtrl.clients[project.client_ix].projects.push(project);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The approach depends on the context:

1. If you are trying to update a model from another angular controller you can use angular services (angular services are basically singletons in the application) in order to have the same model reference
2. If you are trying to call a method from outside the angular scope you can either:

   2.1. publish your controller function reference to a global namespace (not the best choice)

   2.2. use any event dispatching mechanism and call $scope.apply(function() {manipulate your model }); on event listener

Comment: I am trying to implement 2.2, but I need to insert data into a nested resource and so I need a reference to the parent instance.  When I set $scope.client = client in my angular controller where client is the parent resource, my event listener callback outside of the angular scope is unable to get that client instance.

Comment: Try this: $scope.addProject = function(client){ $scope.apply(function() {
    $scope.client = client;
    $scope.newProject.client_id = client.id;
    project = Project.save($scope.newProject);
    $scope.newProject = {};
})}